# Using git filter-branch for specific commits

Tags: git, github

I'm trying to use the git `filter-branch` feature to remove a file that was recently updated and committed. I tried running the following command:

```
git filter-branch --force --index-filter 'git rm --cached --ignore-unmatch myfile' --prune-empty --tag-name-filter cat -- 6f7fda9..HEAD
```

However this only removes the file from the master branch, and I want it removed from all branches.

Starting with commit `6f7fda9` to `HEAD` I want the file removed. Is the command I'm running wrong?

Answer (score 4):

Your requirements as stated are contradictory.  Specifically

> I want it removed from all branches.

and

> Starting with commit 6f7fda9 to HEAD I want the file removed.

need to be reconciled.  I suspect this comes down to an inaccurate understanding of commit ranges - which are only sort-of a thing in git.

Consider this commit graph:

```
x -- 6f7fda9 -- A -- B -- C -- F <--(master)
                 \                        ^(HEAD)
                  D -- E <--(branch)
```

So `HEAD` is at `master` which is at `F`; and there's a branch which was (apparently) created from `A` (after `6f7fda9` but before `HEAD`).

Now the question is, given this graph what does `6f7fda9..HEAD` mean?  And unfortunately, the answer isn't what a lot of people intuitively think.

`6f7fda9..HEAD` is short for `HEAD ^6f7fda9` - meaning "everything reachable from `HEAD` but *not* reachable from `6f7fda9`".  "Reachable" means "the commit itself, and any commits you find by following parent pointers".  So in this case, it means `A`, `B`, `C`, and `F`; but not `x` or `6f7fda9` (because they're reachable from `6f7fda9`) and also not `D`, or `E` (because they aren't reachable from `HEAD`).

There are several ways to get `filter-branch` to process all the branches.  For example you could

```
git filter-branch --force --index-filter 'git rm --cached --ignore-unmatch myfile' --prune-empty --tag-name-filter cat -- --all
```

But this will include all refs (not just all branches); if that's a problem

```
git filter-branch --force --index-filter 'git rm --cached --ignore-unmatch myfile' --prune-empty --tag-name-filter cat -- --branches
```

One other caveat - if you specifically *don't* want commits before `6f7fda9` rewritten, then you need to include one or more negative commit references.  But assuming you *do* intend to include `6f7fda9` itself, you'd exclude its parent (not itself).

```
git filter-branch --force --index-filter 'git rm --cached --ignore-unmatch myfile' --prune-empty --tag-name-filter cat -- ^6f7fda9^ --branches
```

If `6f7fda9` is a merge, you'd have to list negative commit references for each of its parents.

Answer (score 1):

`git filter-branch -- --all` runs the filter on all branches. So:

```
git filter-branch --force --index-filter 'git rm --cached --ignore-unmatch myfile' --prune-empty --tag-name-filter cat -- --all
```

Answer (score 1):

> I want [the file] removed from all branches

It's important to realize that *branches* are almost (but not quite) irrelevant.  What matters are the *commits*.

You literally cannot change any existing commit, and Git does not try.  What `git filter-branch` does is that it *copies* commits.  That is, for each commit to be filtered, Git extracts the original into a temporary work area, applies your filter(s), and then makes a *new* commit from the result.

If the new commit is bit-for-bit identical to the original commit, it re-uses the actual underlying object in the repository database.  If not—and the purpose is to result in "not"—the original commit remains, while the new copy gets a new, different hash ID.  If we use uppercase letters to stand in for commit hash IDs, and remember that each commit stores the hash ID of its *parent* commit, we can draw the originals this way:

```
... <-F <-G <-H <-I   <-- master
```

A branch *name* like `master` remembers the hash ID of the *last* commit.  That commit remembers the hash ID of its parent, which remembers another hash ID of another parent, and so on: `master` lets Git *find* commit `I`, which finds commit `H`, which finds commit `G`, and so on.

With `git filter-branch` we tell Git: *extract commit `F` and maybe make some change to it and then re-commit.*  If nothing changes in `F`, we stick with the actual hash ID.  Then we have Git extract commit `G` and make some change.  This time, perhaps we remove a sensitive file.  So we make a new commit that's like `G` but different: it gets a new, different hash ID, which we can call `G'`.  Commit `G'` still has commit `F` as its parent:

```
...--F--G--H--I   <-- master
      \
       G'
```

We then extract `H` and apply the filter.  Even if nothing else changes, we need our new commit to point back to `G'`, so filter-branch ensures that this happens, and therefore we get a commit `H'` that points back to `G'`.  We repeat for `I` and the result is:

```
...--F--G--H--I   <-- master
      \
       G'-H'-I'
```

The final step is for `git filter-branch` to rewrite each of the branch *names*.  The name `master` must now point to commit `I'`, with its new and different hash, not to shabby old icky `I`.

**The names that `git filter-branch` rewrites at the end of its processing are all the names you identified positively on the command line.**  This part is a little tricky: `git filter-branch` takes, as one / some of its arguments, strings that are suitable for `git rev-list`.  These can be *positive references* like `master`, or *negative references* like `^develop` or `^6f7fda9`.

A *negative reference* tells Git: *don't bother with these commits*.  If you use `^6f7fda9` to skip commit `6f7fda9` and anything "before" (graph-wise) that commit, `git filter-branch` will not have to spend any computer-time working on that commit.

The expression `6f7fda9..HEAD` is shorthand for `^6f7fda9 HEAD`, and `HEAD` means *the current branch name*.  So this is a *positive reference* to one branch name (such as `master`), and one negative reference by hash ID.

You can name *all* your branch names with `--branches`.  You can name all your *references* (including things that are not branch names) with `--all`.  Filter-branch will only rewrite the positive references, but it will rewrite *all* of them.  Be a bit careful with this as this can rewrite `refs/stash` for instance.

When you *do* rewrite any branch, tag, or other name that refers to some commit that *does* contain the file you *don't* want to have, you'll get things like:

```
                    tip2   [abandoned]
                   /
...--good--bad--...--tip   [abandoned]
       \
        copied--...--tip'   <-- branch1
                   \
                    tip2'   <-- branch2
```

If you *don't* rewrite some name that points anywhere to any of the commits from `bad` on down (rightward), those names will still point to the "bad" commits that have the file you want to be rid of.  (Remember that in these particular graph drawings that I do on StackOverflow, earlier / parent commits are to the left, later / child commits are to the right.)